# Native menu selectmenu jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jquery select menu

Here is code from View

```
  <li>
  <%= select_tag 'search[adults]', options_for_select(adults_collection, @default_lsp[:adults]), class: 'custom',data: { native_menu: false, iconpos: 'noicon'} %>
</li>
```

Or clean html

```
 <select name="search[adults]" id="search_adults" class="custom" data-native-menu="false" data-iconpos="noicon" style="display: none;"><option value="1">1 vuxen</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">2 vuxna</option>
<option value="3">3 vuxna</option>
<option value="4">4 vuxna</option>
<option value="5">5 vuxna</option>
<option value="6">6 vuxna</option>
<option value="7">7 vuxna</option>
<option value="8">8 vuxna</option>
<option value="9">9 vuxna</option></select>
```

If you click a dropdown and hold down the mouse button you can't select anything.

I need to make click to dropdown and it will opens and I can select smth without realeasing mouse (some kind of drag n drop I think).

How I can do this?

Comment: You cannot achieve that behaviour with a standard `select` control. As it's also non-intuitive behaviour, as no web controls work like that (due to the fact that click and drag is usually used to move or select elements), it's unlikely that you'll be able to modify an existing plugin to do this, you will need to create it yourself.

Comment: Can you give some links where I can see info about how to do it?  @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Not really as there's no single source. You need to handle multiple events (mousedown, mousemove, mouseup) to open your menu, highlight the one being moused over and then select it on mouseup. If you research all those event handlers I'm sure you'll manage it. If you do get stuck, feel free to ask another question but please include all relevant code.